# PostgreSQL text search in Django not working as expected

Tags: django, python-3.x, postgresql, django-rest-framework, full-text-search

I am implementing a search function for my API to return the object's properties when requested. So far I have tried to use **Full Text Search** which is usable but it has these annoying things: words have to be spelled correctly for the results to be returned and partial search, for example "appl" instead of "apple", won't work. I have also tried **Trigram Similarity** but it failed for long sentences. How do I implement a search function that is both accurate and fuzzy in Django?

*This works*

[image]

*This won't work*

[image]
[image]

This is my **views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from .models import Object_Locations
from .serializers import Object_LocationsSerializer
from django.contrib.postgres.search import SearchVector, SearchQuery


def index(request):
   return render(request, 'main/base.html', {})

@api_view(['GET',])
def LocationsList(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        vector = SearchVector('name', 'desc', 'catergory')
        query = request.GET.get('search')

        if query:
            locations = Object_Locations.objects.annotate(search=vector,).filter(search=SearchQuery(query))
        else:
            locations = Object_Locations.objects.all()

        serializer = Object_LocationsSerializer(locations, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the **[SearchQuery](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/postgres/search/#searchquery)** documentation :

> **SearchQuery** translates the terms the user provides into a search query object that the database compares to a search vector. By default, all the words the user provides are passed through the stemming algorithms, and then it looks for matches for all of the resulting terms.
>
> If **search_type** is **'plain'**, which is the default, the terms are treated as separate keywords. If **search_type** is **'phrase'**, the terms are treated as a single phrase. If **search_type** is **'raw'**, then you can provide a formatted search query with terms and operators.

In the code above the **SearchQuery** with the search phrase *"a blac husky"* is translated to a SQL code like:

```
... @@ plainto_tsquery('a blac husky') ...
```

So if you want to have results with similar search phrases it's possible to combine query terms:

```
from django.contrib.postgres.search import SearchQuery, SearchVector
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response

from .models import Object_Locations
from .serializers import Object_LocationsSerializer


def index(request):
return render(request, 'main/base.html', {})


@api_view(['GET',])
def LocationsList(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        vector = SearchVector('name', 'desc', 'catergory')
        query_terms = request.GET.get('search')
        query_raw = ' | '.join(query_terms.split())
        query = SearchQuery(query_raw, search_type='raw')
        if query.value:
            locations = Object_Locations.objects.annotate(search=vector).filter(search=query)
        else:
            locations = Object_Locations.objects.all()
        serializer = Object_LocationsSerializer(locations, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

In the above code the **SearchQuery** with the search phrase *"a blac husky"* is translated to a SQL code like:

```
... @@ plainto_tsquery('a | blac | husky') ...
```

It's possible to use logical operation to combine SearchQuery as described in the documentation I linked.

If you want to deepen further you can read an **article** that I wrote on the subject:

**"[Full-Text Search in Django with PostgreSQL](https://www.paulox.net/2017/12/22/full-text-search-in-django-with-postgresql)"**

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will definitely check out your article. I have another question, can we combine this with Trigram Similarity to improve it even more like when we type _"a blac husk"_ it will still display the result. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes in the article I wrote example to use trigram and fts togheter